# .NET Core - regex matches whole string instead of group

Tags: regex, asp.net-core

I tested my regex on regex101.com, it returns 3 groups

text :

```
<CloseResponse>SESSION_ID</CloseResponse>
```

regex :

```
(<.*>)([\s\S]*?)(<\/.*>)
```

in C#, I get **only one match** and one **group that contains the whole string instead of just the SESSION_ID**

I expect the code to return only **SESSION_ID**

I tried finding a global option but there don't seem to be any

here is my code

```
Regex rg = new Regex(@"<.*>([\s\S]*?)<\/.*>");
MatchCollection matches = rg.Matches(tag);
if (matches.Count > 0) ////////////////////////////////// only one match
{
    if (matches[0].Groups.Count > 0)
    {
        Group g = matches[0].Groups[0];
        return g.Value; //////////////////// = <CloseResponse>SESSION_ID</CloseResponse>
    }
}
return null;
```

thanks for helping me on this

Comment: It should be `matches[0].Groups[1];` to get the first capturing group

Comment: If you have XML a better idea would be to use LINQ to XML through eg XDocument or XElement instead of regex

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work this way

```
string input = "<OpenResult>SESSION_ID</OpenResult>";

// ... Use named group in regular expression.
Regex expression = new Regex(@"(<.*>)(?<middle>[\s\S]*)(<\/.*>)");

// ... See if we matched.
Match match = expression.Match(input);
if (match.Success)
{
    // ... Get group by name.
    string result = match.Groups["middle"].Value;
    Console.WriteLine("Middle: {0}", result);
}
// Done.
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: What's the difference? It looks like the only thing that changed is reading a different group. You could use `Groups[1]` to do the same thing. Naming groups is important for other reasons though - you can actually work with the groups as if they were fields eg in a LINQ query, eg `matches.OfType<Match>().Where(m=>m.Groups['content"].Value=="SESSION_ID")` will get you all matches with SESSION_ID.

Comment: Or you could use LINQ to XML directly

Comment: If the input string contains nested node, like this `<div><OpenResult>SESSION_ID</OpenResult></div>`, you could use the following expression to find the special node: `(<.*>)(?<middle>[\s\S]*)(<\/.*>)`, then, using the `match.Groups[1].Value` to get the Session_ID.

Answer (score 0):

Use non-capturing group if you want whole string as result: `(?:)`

`(?:<.*>)(?:[\s\S]*?)(?:<\/.*>)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qa9cfI/1)

If you just want to capture session id use this:

`(?:<.*>)([\s\S]*?)(?:<\/.*>)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qa9cfI/2)